# How to replace the face of an ImageView with an image (Face Detection)?

Tags: android, face-detection

I am working with Face Detection in Android.

I can detect the face using [`FaceDetector.Face`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/FaceDetector.Face.html). I want to replace the detected face with another face and can be able to move the new face. How can I get the face coordinates or the position of the face? If I get the position of the face I can easily replace the new face on that.

Please provide some solutions for this.

Thanks.

Comment: You find solution for this or not ? I have same issue..